# running ACCELEO from ACCELEO on the DSL contained in model elements

Tags: eclipse-emf, acceleo, mda

I have a UML activity with OpaqueActions containing a DSL. The DSL grammar is expressed by means of XText thus there is an EMF ECORE model and editor for it. I have an ACCELEO M2T transformation transforming UML activities in text and I'd like to trigger (from such transformation) another transformation (from the DSL meta-model to text) providing as input the DSL containing in the opaque actions of the activity. Is there any way to easily do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two generators, one for your UML transformation and the second one for your DSL and call the first one from the second one once you encounter your DSL elements while navigating in your UML model.

Comment: I see but I guess the DSL will appear just like a String while in the UML transformation. How can I apply a transformation to its root element if the whole DSL model (contained into an opaque action) is managed as a string?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures). Feel free to flag this comment as obsolete once you've read it.

Comment: You would have to use a Java service in order to call Xtext to transform the string into a model that the rest of the generation will be able to process.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested and it almost works. I still have a small problem in the acceleo side, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966797/meshing-acceleo-with-xtext